# Step by step guide to run angular js app with Jasmine and Karma

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I am looking for a beginner's guide to running angular js app with Jasmine and Karma. Very step by step and thorough guide. I am a beginner in unit testing with JS framework. Can someone please point me to some right resources ?

I tried to follow https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial for angular-phonecat-master and npm is just giving me a bunch of errors.

I want something very simple. Probably not involving NPM at this point. I am trying to setup on windows.

Comment: Have you looked at [angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) project?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the quickest way to get started with AngularJS. The unit tests are written in Jasmine and run with the Karma Test Runner.

https://github.com/angular/angular-seed

The README goes through all the necessary steps to set up a sample AngularJS application that you can use as a starting point for your own application.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but my npm is erroring out like below when i try npm install from git command prompt:                             Error: No compatible version found: shelljs@'^0.2.6'
Valid install targets:
["0.0.1","0.0.2","0.0.3","0.0.4","0.0.5","0.0.6","0.0.
,"0.1.1","0.1.2","0.1.3","0.1.4","0.2.0","0.2.1","0.2.
,"0.2.6","0.3.0","0.0.1-alpha1","0.0.2-pre1","0.0.4-pr
e2","0.0.5-pre3","0.0.5-pre4","0.0.6-pre1","0.0.6-pre

Comment: That is a different question but let´s see. I assume you mean from GitBash. You do not need it for this. You can install npm in Windows just by going to http://nodejs.org/download/ and selecting an installer. The npm tool is bundled with it. So, just run npm from a normal command console (cmd). You can check with npm -v. Also, you need to run npm install from the root of the project, where package.json is. So, clone the repository, open a console, go to the root of the project and run npm install after installing node.js in your machine. That should do.

Comment: You are right. Its a different question. I just created a new thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642989/npm-start-throwing-errors